SQL Developer Custom Formatting
ive setup most of my formatting to the way i like it, theres just 2 elements left i cannot figure out.

Semicolon on new line
New line and indent on joins

SELECT UU.USER_NAME
     , UU.USER_TITLE
     , UU.USER_FIRST_NAME
     , UU.USER_LAST_NAME
     , UU.USER_EMAIL_1
     , UU.IS_ACTIVE
     , XWS.XWORKSPACE_ID
     , XT.TILE_CLASS
     , XT.TITLE
     , XT.XTILE_ID
     , DBP.DSHBRD_PORTLET_ID
     , DBP.PORTLET_NAME
     , DBT.DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE
FROM UCL_USER            UU
    LEFT JOIN XWORKSPACE          XWS
        ON UU.UCL_USER_ID = XWS.UCL_USER_ID
    LEFT JOIN XTILE               XT
        ON XWS.XWORKSPACE_ID = XT.XWORKSPACE_ID
    LEFT JOIN DSHBRD_PORTLET      DBP
        ON JSON_VALUE(XT.CONTENT, '$.portlet') = DBP.DSHBRD_PORTLET_ID
    LEFT JOIN DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE DBT
        ON DBP.DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE_ID = DBT.DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE_ID
WHERE UU.COMPANY_ID = 2
      AND PORTLET_NAME LIKE '%MP %'
      AND IS_ACTIVE = '1'
ORDER BY UU.USER_NAME
       , XWS.XWORKSPACE_ID
       , XT.TITLE
       , DBP.PORTLET_NAME
;

Nothing in the Advance formatting seems to do what i want, so the only other option is the custom formatting.
Currently when i use the formatter it lines the JOIN/ON up with the FROM and it puts the Semicolon straight after the last character highlighted and it turns out like this
SELECT UU.USER_NAME
     , UU.USER_TITLE
     , UU.USER_FIRST_NAME
     , UU.USER_LAST_NAME
     , UU.USER_EMAIL_1
     , UU.IS_ACTIVE
     , XWS.XWORKSPACE_ID
     , XT.TILE_CLASS
     , XT.TITLE
     , XT.XTILE_ID
     , DBP.DSHBRD_PORTLET_ID
     , DBP.PORTLET_NAME
     , DBT.DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE
FROM UCL_USER            UU
LEFT JOIN XWORKSPACE          XWS
ON UU.UCL_USER_ID = XWS.UCL_USER_ID
LEFT JOIN XTILE               XT
ON XWS.XWORKSPACE_ID = XT.XWORKSPACE_ID
LEFT JOIN DSHBRD_PORTLET      DBP
ON JSON_VALUE(XT.CONTENT
           , '$.portlet') = DBP.DSHBRD_PORTLET_ID
LEFT JOIN DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE DBT
ON DBP.DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE_ID = DBT.DSHBRD_PORTLET_TYPE_ID
WHERE UU.COMPANY_ID = 2
      AND PORTLET_NAME LIKE '%MP %'
      AND IS_ACTIVE = '1'
ORDER BY UU.USER_NAME
       , XWS.XWORKSPACE_ID
       , XT.TITLE
       , DBP.PORTLET_NAME;

